# What does "crushing" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does "crushing" mean in the sentence "Instagram has been crushing these past few years as the popularity of Facebook has dropped significantly"

Comment: Is there a problem looking it up in an online dictionary?

Comment: In this case, it's an idiomatic phrase for *killing it*, *knocking it out of the park*, or *leading the competition.* You won't find this particular definition in the main dictionaries I've looked at. More normally, however, I'd expect to hear *crushing* ***it***.

Answer (score 1):

"Crushing", or more often "crushing it", means something like "[succeeding emphatically](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Crushing%20it)".